# Is there any way to know when NOT to use my Oyster card?

Tags: trains, london, oyster-card

I have been living in London for many years yet I still can't figure out when I am not allowed to use my Oyster card and I have to ask every time I suspect that it can't be used.

Two recent examples:

- Trains from Paddington to Slough for example stop at Ealing Broadway, Southall, Hayes & Harlington, West Drayton and Langley

I know for sure that I can use my Oyster to go to Ealing Broadway as I have done it hundreds of times and I am very sure that I cant use it to go to Slough.
I cant remember which of the rest of stations are within the *coverage* of the Oyster card. There are no signs at the station to explain that.

- Trains from St Pancras to Ebbsfleet

If I remember correctly I can get off at Stratford, no problem using the Oyster card but you have to buy a ticket if you are going to Ebbsfleet

Again no signs and no way to tell not even the ticket machine warns you about that.

Is there something I am not aware of?

Comment: +1 I struggled with this too. Sometimes you hear announcements on the trains themselves like "Please be aware that oyster cards may only be used as far as X" but it's a bit late once you're on the train!

Comment: @user568458 lucky you, NEVER heard such warring and as you said it would be too late

Comment: TFL have a page ["Where you can use oyster"](https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/oyster/using-oyster/where-you-can-use-oyster) which includes a PDF map, but it seems a bit complicated and arbitrary, can't see any clear pattern. I'm not even 100% sure if the locations on the map can all use oyster or not

Comment: @user568458 All locations on the map except the non-tube Heathrow stations are Oyster-compatible. However, the Merstham-Gatwick section to the south are only for Oyster pay-as-you-go, and aren't covered by any Travelcard

Comment: You can always ask the staff manning the ticket gateline at your starting station if Oyster will be valid to your destination, they should know or otherwise have a map to check on. Ask before you go through though, so you can go buy a paper ticket if needed!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consult this map, which marks all zones and the stations located within them  http://content.tfl.gov.uk/london-rail-and-tube-services-map.pdf

While I haven't bothered to memorise every single zone Limit (since I'm not a UK resident, but a fairly frequent visitor), I do know where the outer boundaries of the TFL area are located, which is the most important thing.

On the route to Reading, you can go as far as West Drayton, and as you say, up to Stratford on the high-speed line

Comment: Are you sure this is for Oyster card? I see Gatwick airport on the map and as far as I know Heathrow is the only airport you can travel to using your Oyster card

Comment: There's also a bit more info around this on https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/oyster/using-oyster/where-you-can-use-oyster#on-this-page-2

Comment: Do the same rules also apply for contactless?

Comment: @JonathanReez Contactless is a form of pay-as-you-go, only using a regular bank/credit card rather than an Oyster card. So yes, whatever rules apply for pay-as-you-go using Oyster also apply to contactless. The main difference is that contactless, unlike Oyster, has weekly (Monday-Sunday) fare caps, which vary depending on the zone. Similar to the daily caps with pay-as-you-go using both Oyster and contactless

Comment: @Crazydre are you saying that using contactless can save money over Oyster?

Comment: @Ulkoma Not for residents. Basically the weekly contactless cap sees to it that you pay no more in a calendar week (Mon-Sun) than you would for a 7-day Travelcard (which is only for Oyster). If you use monthly or annual Travelcards (also only for Oyster), you should continue doing so

Comment: @Ulkoma It can save money under the right circumstances. Monday to sunday contactless capping is the same price as Weekly travelcards on oyster. Weekly travelcards have the advantage that they can be bought to start on any day. Monday to Sunday capping has the advantage that you don't have to decide in advance whether to buy a travelcard or not.

Comment: @ulkoma, the area where you can use oyster has been gradually growing. As the map indicates Gatwick is within the pay as you go area, but not within any zone, so special fares apply. There are a few other small areas like that. Special fares and lack of travelcard/capping also apply on Heathrow express,  Southeastern high speed and Emeriates air line despite being within the zones.

Comment: There are also now some areas where you can use contactless PAYG but not oyster due to technical limitations with how oyster is implemented.